# Accessing variables of anonymous class

Tags: java, java-threads, anonymous-class

Is there a way to access variables defined in anonymous class
example:

```
    class someClass{
    returntype someMethod(){
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
           ANrequest request;
           ANresponse response;

           @Override
           public void run() {
               request = somerequest.build();
               response = request.executeForObjectList(Myclass.class);
           }
       });
       t.start();
       t.join();
      if (this)
         return response.isSucces();
      else
         return request.something();

}
}
```

What I found out is that I can define instance variable and use them inside anonymous class -> but I would like not to have to do that

```
 class someClass{
    ANrequest request;
    ANresponse response;
    returntype someMethod(){
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

           @Override
           public void run() {
               request = somerequest.build();
               response = request.executeForObjectList(Myclass.class);
           }
       });
       t.start();
       t.join();
      if (this)
         return response.isSucces();
      else
         return request.something();

}
}
```

or we can make final one element array inside the method and than use its field to pass the result, which is bad practise I think.

```
class someClass{
    ANrequest request;
    ANresponse response;
    returntype someMethod(){

    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
           final ANrequest request[]=new Anrequest[1]; 
          final ANresponse response[]=new Anresponse[1];
           @Override
           public void run() {
               request[0] = somerequest.build();
               response[1] = request.executeForObjectList(Myclass.class);
           }
       });
       t.start();
       t.join();
      if (this)
         return response[0].isSucces();
      else
         return request[1].something();

 }
}
```

So my question is : Is there anyway to define variables inside anonymous class and then later access them:

something like this:

```
Runnable r= new Runnable () {
           ANrequest request;
           ANresponse response;

           @Override
           public void run() {
               request = somerequest.build();
               response = request.executeForObjectList(Myclass.class);
           }
       };
```

later:

`r.response` or `r.request`

Comment: Why not just make it a named class with getter methods?

Comment: in the class `someClass` I have multiple methods and inside every method i have to write different `run()` method i.e start a new thread with specific run method

Comment: Then perhaps they can be anonymous subclasses of the named class?

Comment: You could have a synchronized "container"-class that stores the stuff and share the reference.

Comment: @akuzminykh I think i've found the solution: I've defined `abstract` class which extends `Thread` and holds the necessary fields in that class I declare `run()` as abstract method and than I create an `anonymous class` which extends that `abstract class` and then I simply override the run method and use the fields

Comment: @user12394078 Sounds good!

Answer (score 0):

I just learnt of this today, but if you use `var` instead of `Runnable` when declaring your anonymous class, you'll be able to access it's fields (even if they are private it seems).

```
var r = new Runnable () {
       ANrequest request;
       ANresponse response;

       @Override
       public void run() {
           request = somerequest.build();
           response = request.executeForObjectList(Myclass.class);
       }
   };
System.out.println(r.request)
System.out.println(r.response)
```